# Diffrences on Database between Sharepoint 2010 and 2013?

Tags: migration

How Much databases has Sharepoint 2010, and how much has got a Sharepoint 2013?

I want to prepere to migration from Sharepoint 2010 and 2013, and i want to know a differences on data base, how much they are and what can be problems on Migration.

If there any of differences in Sharepoint bases 2010 and Sharepoint 2013 ?

Could Sameone describe the Diferences on database from 2010, and 2013?

Is there a main comunication language with DataBase is CAML ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to look into detach attach method for migration. From what i know your looking to migrate from 2010 (SQL 2008) to 2013 (SQL 2012).

The content databases would be the same as would most things! there would be conversions going on but that is not done on your side!

once you have done your detach attach method to migrate the content DB you can that put the site into 2010 mode and than convert to 2013!

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alimaz/archive/2012/07/17/upgrading-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013-step-by-step.aspx

as for the requirements if your looking for that and more indepth detail of what is going on refer to this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Before you upgrade from SharePoint 2010 Products to SharePoint 2013, you should take time to test an upgrade process and understand the issues that you might face in an actual upgrade. After you perform a test upgrade, or after you upgrade your actual databases, you might find issues that have to be addressed. After you address issues, you can restart the upgrade to try again.

Have a look at the below links for more details,

1. [Upgrade databases from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303436.aspx)
2. [Test and troubleshoot an upgrade to SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382642%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The amount of databases shouldn't be an issue, also it depends on which Service Applications are installed and enabled. (eg. Search Service uses 4 Databases) We have 18 databases, plus about 9 content DBs.

For migration we didn't have big issues. Check this link:

1. [Upgrade content databases to SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx)

And the Link from Karthik Jaganathan about database upgrade in general.